# How to convert a dataset to a sql datasource or object datasource for use on a grid

Tags: vb.net, dataset, sqldatasource, objectdatasource

I have a code which on button click, executes a sql string builder who's result is sent to a dataset. I would like to send these results from the dataset back to a datasource (sql datasource or object datasource) that way I can reference it on my grid. Any Ideas? Here is what part of my code looks like:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)   
Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sql3 = "[dbo].[table1]"
    Dim connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DataConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql3, New SqlConnection(connectionString))

    Dim strSql As New StringBuilder
    strSql.Clear()

    If RbtnList1.SelectedValue = 1 Then
        strSql.Append(" Select * from table1 where col1 = 5")

 If NOT (DDL1.SelectedValue = 0) Then
     strSql.Append(" AND ((c.col2 = @param1))")
 End If
     command.CommandText = strSql.ToString 
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", DDL1.SelectedValue)

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
Dim dataset As New DataSet
adapter.Fill(dataset)
GdVw1.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)
GdVw1.DataBind()
```

I would like to Bind this data to a datasource for example "datasource1" so my grid will look something like this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GdVw1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
 </asp:GridView>
```

My final goal is to be able to have a grid that allows paging which actually works and is able to export to excel when there are thousands of data. Right now it doesn't work because the my datasource is on the back end as a dataset.